# OData no http resource was found that matches the request uri

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm having some trouble getting my Odata service working with my MVC 4 site.

Can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my WebApiConfig:

```
  public static class WebApiConfig
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Register method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="config">The config.</param>
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel(), new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
        config.EnsureInitialized();
    }
    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.Namespace = "ThisClassesNamespace";
        builder.ContainerName = "DefaultContainer";
        builder.EntitySet<QueryRequest>("QueryRequests");
        var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
        return edmModel;
    }
}
```

here is the global.asax's application_start method:

```
  protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Application["Name"] = "Administration Web Console";
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        Error += MvcApplication_Error;

        var maplayerDao = new MapLayerDao();
        maplayerDao.UpdateProvisioningData();

        var factory = new CustomControllerFactory();
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(factory);

    }
```

finally, here is what the controler's get method looks like

```
 public class QueryRequestsController : ODataController
{
    private static ODataValidationSettings _validationSettings = new ODataValidationSettings();
    private QueryRequestDao dao = new QueryRequestDao();

    // GET: odata/QueryRequests
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetQueryRequests()
    {
        // validate the query.
        try
        {
           // queryOptions.Validate(_validationSettings);
        }
        catch (ODataException ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }

         return Ok<IEnumerable<QueryRequest>>(dao.GetQueryRequests());
    }
```

I can get the metadata just fine at http://10.78.14.177:8040/odata/

which gives me:

```
{
 "@odata.context":"http://10.78.14.177:8040/odata/$metadata","value":[
{
  "name":"QueryRequests","kind":"EntitySet","url":"QueryRequests"
}
```

]
}

but when I go to http://10.78.14.177:8040/odata/QueryRequests
I get No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://10.78.14.177:8040/odata/QueryRequests'.

I think the MVC routing is getting this request and it is not going to the OData service... but I'm not sure what the fix is.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should be able to confirm your hypothesis about the MVC routing engine intercepting the request by commenting out the following lines: 

`AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();`
`RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` Then try to browse to the url again.

Comment: yeah I tried it and didn't see any change.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in CustomControllerFactory does it end up in there?

Comment: I actually found it today, I had the 1.3 and 2.2 versions of the microsoft odata stuff both referenced in my project, and I think that was causing it to behave all eratically. once I removed the older version, everything started working.